# What's an easy way to see whether a mount point has been made shared?

Tags: linux, mount

`mount` has an option `--make-shared` as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-mount-namespaces.html). However, how do I find out if a particular mount point has been made shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux exposes information about mounted filesystems in `/proc/mounts`. The [sharing options](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) are too recent to show up in that file, but they do show up in `/proc/self/mountinfo`¹. The documentation for this file is in [`filesystems/proc.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) in the kernel documentation. The file is generated by [`show_mountinfo` in `fs/namespace.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/namespace.c#L1005). A sample line looks like this:

```
42 18 98:0 / /mount_point rw shared:1 - ext3 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=continue
                             ^^^^^^^^
```

The format of the first 6 fields is fixed. Then come zero or more tagged fields, such as `shared:GROUP`, `master:GROUP`, `propagate_from:GROUP` or `unbindable`, indicating the mount's role in a peer group if any. The `-` introduces the filesystem-specific part, always composed of the filesystem type name, device name and filesystem-specific mount options.

Thus:

```
</proc/self/mountinfo awk -vmount_point='/mount/point' '
$5 == mount_point {
    i = 7;
    while ($i != "-") {if ($i ~ /^shared:/) exit 0; ++i}
    exit 1;
}'
```

¹  <sub>On recent enough Linux kernels, each process has its own filesystem namespace and `/proc/mounts` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/mounts`.</sub>